# Adding ActionSherlock creates Eclipse Error R cannot be resolved to a Variable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Am trying to create a Action Tab bar example with ActionSherlock library. Once the Library is added to Project, Am getting the error in MainActivity.

Error R cannot be resolved to a Variable

SherlockLirary AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.actionbarsherlock"
    android:versionCode="440"
    android:versionName="4.4.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application />

</manifest>
```

Application's AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidbegin.actionbarsherlocktutorial"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.androidbegin.actionbarsherlocktutorial.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Added Error Screens[image]

[image]

Comment: Try cleaning the project properties by clicking on the project(Menu bar) and selecting Clean Project.

Alternatively, you may have not selected the Android library version from project right-click->properties->Android.

Answer (score 0):

Import ActionBarSherlock lib project as an Android project.

Then select your project goto properties select Android. Scroll down below the SDK version. Add library project.

Clean all projects.

-- answered from my Nexus 5

Answer (score 0):

In your java file import R of your project instead of import.android.R. Sometime it happens